# Length() is counting \0 as a character

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that has a column named `Description`. The column is of size `varchar(100)` with default as `NULL`.

I want to select from the table where `length(Description)>0`.

There are some rows where Description is empty, but when I check the length it returns 1.

I copied the row from MySQL workbench and pasted it on Notepad++, and I see that the empty Description column has `\0` in it and the length is 1.

How can I NOT count `\0` as a character?

I have tried these:

`select * from MyTable where length(trim(Description))>0;` -->> doesnt work. length is 1 for empty column

`select * from MyTable where Description<>'';` -->> doesnt work. length is 1 for empty column

`select * from MyTable where length(trim(ifnull(Description,'')))>0;` -->> doesnt work. length is 1 for empty column.

Comment: `select * from MyTable where length(trim(!ifnull(Description,'')))>0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
length(replace(Description,'\0',''))
```

Often people ask the opposite question, how to count the number of occurrences of a string; you use length for that too:

```
(length(Description) - length(replace(Description,somestring,''))) / length(somestring)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `\0` represents the ASCII null character.  One approach here would be to check the length of the column after removing it:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE LENGTH(REPLACE(TRIM(Description), CHAR(0x00 using utf8), '')) > 0;
```